# Why dvips gives checksum mismatch warning if \magnification is used?

Tags: fonts

Run `tex` on this `test.tex` file:

```
\magnification\magstep1
\font\x=frcr10 \x hello \bye
```

Then run `dvips test`. Output is `dvips: Checksum mismatch in font frcr10`.

What's wrong with font `frcr10` and how to fix the warning?

(font `frcr10` is provided by `texlive-fonts-extra` package)

---

**EDIT**

I use `pk` fonts. This is my `~/.dvipsrc`:

```
q
p /dev/null
```

Comment: Here is where it comes from in the source but I don't know what is causing it: https://github.com/TeX-Live/texlive-source/blob/ea6931ac58a820228f6a8bbdeae770f4e17f613c/texk/dvipsk/loadfont.c#L370

Comment: No issue on my TeX Live. Anyway, it's an innocuous warning.

Comment: @egreg I'm using Debian Linux. `dvips` version 5.998, `kpathsea` version 6.3.1. Which system are you using?

Comment: @Igor: Probably egreg is using pfb with correct map files, and
you are using pk. Sorry if I'm wrong.

Comment: @AkiraKakuto Indeed, I use pk. See **EDIT**.